# perl5 method test "can" not working correctly in new version

Tags: perl

In perl 5.8

```
perl  -e ' print "a" if AXXXXXXXXXXXXX::->can("isa");'
perl  -e ' print "a" if AXXXXXXXXXXXXX->can("isa");'
```

print "nothing" , means method test failed;

In perl 5.17

```
perl  -e ' print "a" if AXXXXXXXXXXXXX::->can("isa");'
perl  -e ' print "a" if AXXXXXXXXXXXXX->can("isa");'
```

print "a", means method test succeed;

I want to know why difference ?

and why un-esixt  and un-loaded module "AXXXXXXXXX" test pass in new version of perl ?

very thank you :)

Comment: Why are you using a development version 5.17.x when the stable 5.18.0 is available?  It might be a bug fixed since then.  Alternatively, it might still be present in 5.18.  The maintainers probably won't be interested in a bug report against 5.17; you'd have to show it is a problem in 5.18.

Comment: yes i test on 5.16 it works like 5.8.

Answer (score 5):

From [perldoc perl5180delta](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5180delta.html):

> "$class->can", "$class->isa", and "$class->DOES" now return correct
>   results, regardless of whether that package referred to by $class
>   exists [perl #47113].

This change was introduced in order to fix a long-open bug report regarding `UNIVERSAL::can`. The change does result in arguably incompatible changes in behavior, but based on existing discussion, the change in behavior is not seen as a bug and is not likely to be reverted.

[perl #47113](https://rt.perl.org/rt3/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=47113) documents the original bug report and the recent fix

[perl #118513](https://rt.perl.org/rt3/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=118513) is a bug reporting the behavior you observed -- closed as rejected

It is very likely that there is another means to accomplish what you are attempting do with the code examples in your question. I'd recommend searching for that which you are trying to accomplish.

If you're trying to test to see if a specific module is loaded, you can use something similar to [the approach adopted by Params::Validate::Dependencies](https://github.com/DrHyde/perl-modules-Params-Validate-Dependencies/commit/03483a538aa705521bbc280b5d3260046905c583) in response to this change:

```
no strict 'refs'
unless(@{"${class}::ISA"}) [...]
```

There's likely another way -- again, search for what you're trying to accomplish, now that you know about this change to Perl.

Answer (score 1):

`can` was buggy. As you're reported, `can` would report that some <s>modules</s> namespaces didn't have a method name `isa`.

```
>perl5.16.3 -E"say 'xxx'->can('isa') ? q{can} : q{can't}"
can't
```

Yet all namespaces have such a method.

```
>perl5.16.3 -E"say eval { 'xxx'->isa('yyy'); 1 } ? q{can} : q{can't}"
can
```

This was [fixed](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5180delta.html) in 5.18.0